# What is the correct path to read a file .txt in java (android)?

Tags: java, android, json, windows

I'm trying to read a file .txt that have a json inside, but I'm getting a FileNotFoundException and obj is null. I supposed that the path is wrong, but I've seen in other questions that this will be correct....

I'm using windows and, yes, I have the file inside this path.

```
   JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
Object obj;

        try {
             obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("C:/Users/Kevin/jsontest.txt"));
        }catch(FileNotFoundException f){

        }
```

Comment: Try printing the stacktrace of the error `f.printStackTrace();` What line does it say the error is coming from?

Comment: This is the error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C/Users/Kevin/json.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Try C:\\Users\\Kevin\\jsontest.txt

Comment: Same error that I comment  above

Comment: Does the file open when you enter C:\Users\Kevin\jsontest.txt in the `Run` window?

Comment: Yes, is open the file

Comment: Android does not have `"C:"` in its path names.

Comment: this:\\Users\\Kevin\\jsontest.txt

Comment: Are you trying to learn coding or writing usable code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this option.

1. Create a folder raw inside the res folder and put here your txt.
2. put this code:

   ```
           Resources res = getResources();
           InputStream in = res.openRawResource(R.raw.jsontest);
           String json = IOUtils.toString(in);
           IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
   ```
3. Put this String in your JsonObject

   JSONObject j = new JSONObject(fakejson);
4. Maybe you need import the Utils. Add this to gradle:

   compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of what are you aiming for, but you can simply check first if the failure was coming from `FileReader` object (or the path) and then add it to `JsonParser` object back .. note: try to put the file in the same workspace that you are writing your java file.

Answer (score 0):

Use Files.lines. Something line this would do the trick, if you want to read line by line.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Readfile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        final Path location = Paths.get("C:/Users/Kevin/jsontest.txt");
        try (Files.lines(location)) {
            lines.forEach(line -> 
                System.out.println(line)
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // we have a problem
        }
    }
}
```

The above would be to process a text file line by line.

If on the other hand you are trying to parse JSON, use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome/).

Comment: I can't do this imports, I'm in android, not sure if this could be the problem...